# How to fetch and display data from access database with vb 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Am just new to vb 2010 and am trying to fetch data from access database (Employees.mdb) but am stack on how to display the data now, anybody with help. Thanks

```
Public Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim LoginUser As String
    LoginUser = LoginForm.TextBoxID.Text ' User Login Name
    DisplayLogin.Text = LoginUser ' Display now user to form

    Dim db As String = "Employees.mdb"

    Dim DatabasePath As String = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\QBook Api\data api\" + db
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(DatabasePath) Then
        Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim Sql As String
        Dim NumOfRows As Integer
        Dim TodayDate As String = Today
        con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = " + DatabasePath

        con.Open() ' Opening oLe Connection

        ' Checking database if we have todays or Searched records
        Sql = "SELECT * FROM Employees INNER JOIN TimeTable ON Employees.EmployeeNo = TimeTable.RefID WHERE Dated = '" & TodayDate & "' "
        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(Sql, con)
        NumOfRows = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If NumOfRows > 0 Then
            ' Here I need to display the data


        Else
            MsgBox("Sorry we don’t have Entry Logs of (" + TodayDate + ")", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Title:="QBook - No entry found")
        End If
        con.Close() ' Closing Connection
    Else

        MsgBox("Unable to get database file in (" + DatabasePath + ")", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)

    End If ' no database found




End Sub
```

any suggestion is appreciated and welcomed

Comment: try to change this WHERE Dated = '" & TodayDate & "' " to this WHERE Dated = #" & TodayDate & "#"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ExecuteScalar` only returns the first column from the first row in your result set so you won't be able to display any data other than that. It's typically used if you're getting a count, sum or something that only returns one value.

If you want to read and display data use `ExecuteReader` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/979byfca(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. You can then use that to bind your result to something like a `DataGridView`.

```
Dim reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

If reader.HasRows() Then
    Dim dt = New DataTable()
    dt.Load(reader)
    dataGridView2.DataSource = dt
Else
    'No log entries to display
End If
```

Comment: but the problem i cant control each value? like convert string from database to uppercase? or test if value is empty.
and how to make the dataGridView1 to always fit my app

Comment: They are really all separate questions, ie "How do I change a value in a DataTable?", "How do I check if a value in a DataTable is empty?", "How do I make a UserControl resize with a form?" and so on. I'm pretty sure they will already have answers if you were to search for them.

Comment: my compliant is not how to check empty, but i would like to have a value for each element which is in the database. in php while you are looping the database i was expecting val = row[val] so i can be able to control 'val'

Comment: You can loop through the `DataReader` if you prefer that rather than loading into `DataTable` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx . Or you can loop through the DataTable itself before you bind it to the grid : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2